# What effect would it make if the SSLv3 protocal is disabled in a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ssl

I have come across a situation where I need to decide whether to disable the SSLV3 protocal in the SharePoint site. I have not come across any answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might have problems if some of your users are still using Windows XP with old versions of IE, or if you are using Windows Server 2008 (before R2).

Many admins are removing not only SSL3, but also SSL2 and a bunch of other ssl algorithms (hashes, etc.) because of the "logjam" vulnerability.

You can use [this tool](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) from nartac.com to conveniently disable all the old, vulnerable ssl algorithms.

Here is an [article from Microsoft on the registry keys affected](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;245030).

You can read more about logjam at these links:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/what-is-logjam-and-how-do-i-prevent-it
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html

Comment: Note that TLS 1.0 must remain active for SharePoint 2013, OOTB. If you install [KB296035](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2960358), you can disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1, if needed.